# ViewController receiving ID instead of the data from a SQLite query

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a view having a Database which has a 'word' table (stores words) and I want to retrieve and send the data to another ViewController, but instead of receiving the actual word, I am getting the `id`.

**Here is my code:**

```
(void)getListData {

//tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dexternotedb.sqlite"];

if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    WordListViewController *temp = APP_DELEGATE.wordListViewController;
    NSLog(@"word id %ld",(long)[temp.wordId integerValue]);

    NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_id=\"%@\"",APP_DELEGATE.wordListViewController.wordId];
    const char *read_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"select query%@",sql);


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, read_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, [temp.wordId integerValue]);

       while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
           NSString *word1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
           [word addObject:word1];
           NSString *meaning1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
           [meaning addObject:meaning1];

           NSString *sentence1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
           [Sentence addObject:sentence1];

       }


    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
} else {
            sqlite3_close(database);
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

Don't use "Select *", because you don't really know the order of the columns, and you are using column index to access them.

So you should use the real names "Select, id, word...."

Second:

All your column retrieval are pointing to the same index 0:

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
```

that is why you are getting the same data (the id), because it has the first index only. So change it to the correct indexes 1, 2, 3... and you will get the correct datas..

Using this SQL (check if the column names are correct)

```
SELECT word_id, word, meaning, sentence FROM words WHERE word_id=\"%@\"
```

Then you can use the correct indexes for the sqlite3_column_text:

```
NSString *word1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
           [word addObject:word1];
           NSString *meaning1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
           [meaning addObject:meaning1];

           NSString *sentence1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
           [Sentence addObject:sentence1];
```

Comment: i have word meaning sentence and wordid in word table ...so can u tell me how to write the select query of it

Comment: if you said the column names correctly, here:   SELECT  wordid, word, meaning, sentence FROM words WHERE word_id=\"%@\

Comment: check the update, it is important you add the correct index to the the sqlite3_column_text function.. also check your column names in the query